# Official or recommended way to install latest mongoDB server on non LTS Ubuntu versions

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, apt, deb

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

This page has official instructions to install the latest [MongoDB server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu).
But this documentation covers only LTS versions.

- 22.04 LTS ("Jammy") (Starting in MongoDB 6.0.4)
- 20.04 LTS ("Focal")
- 18.04 LTS ("Bionic")
- 16.04 LTS ("Xenial")

I am using Ubuntu 23.04. Which is not the LTS version.
I could not find any official way or recommended way to install MongoDB on non LTS ubuntu.

So I am left with two choices

1. Setup wrong repo and install using `sudo apt install`
   `https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse"`
   This repo is for Ubuntu 22.04 using it for Ubuntu 23.04 may break packages.
2. Download `.deb` file and handle dependency manually. This can also break packages.

So I don't want to try both these approaches for installing MongoDB server as they are unsafe.

How can I install latest MongoDB server on Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: You could compile it from source. You'll need several build tools, lots of RAM, disk space, and time.  That's what I do on Fedora and when it completes, it works great.

Comment: Same issue here :shrug: